# Verb forms and usage of lie

Tags: verbs, tenses

My textbook tells me verb forms of 'lie' are : Lie, lay, lain, lying, lies.

So, where does 'lied' fit in? Google search results show that 'lied' is simple past tense form and past participle form of 'lie'. Please enlighten me.

Some usages of 'lain' would also be interesting.

Feel free to point out grammatical errors in my sentences. Thanks

Comment: 'Lied' is the past tense of 'to lie' meaning to deceive. It is a different verb from 'to lie' meaning to lie down.

Comment: Having lain in the grass, he became damp with dew.